# How to extract a list of indices based on a date range and Category match in Excel? [Ver: Standard 2019]

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, excel-2019

I have a column with random date values in random order. I want to extract the indices of any date match which fall between a date range (Column B and C) AND a category match (Column E).

I cannot use any solution which will alter the indices, the Date and Category values should be at its index always. Dates are in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Data Example and Expected Result in Column F:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dates | Start Range | End Range | Category | Category Condition | Indices |
| 11/02/2021 | 11/02/2021 | 11/25/2021 | A | A | 1 |
| 10/22/2021 |  |  | B |  | 3 |
| 11/22/2021 |  |  | A |  | 5 |
| 09/02/2021 |  |  | C |  | 6 |
| 11/15/2021 |  |  | A |  | #NA |
| 11/02/2021 |  |  | A |  | #NA |

Solution Tried:
Using Match and Index formulas, I extracted the indices of Column D in a new column.
Using Match and Index formulas, I extracted the indices of Column A in another column.
Using the same formulas I found out the common indices.
This increased the calculation time by a lot and Excel was not responded time to time.

How can I achieve the expected column F with minimal calculation time?
I cannot upgrade Excel to Office 365, hence unable to use Filter formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$7))+1)/(($A$2:$A$7>=$B$2)*($A$2:$A$7<=$C$2)*($D$2:$D$7=$E$2)),ROW($ZZ1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Scott!